# Difference between classification and regression score in Python scikit learn

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, regression

I'm kind a new for python scikit learning i develop a data mining algorithm using scikit learn classification methods and now i need to find its accuracy. first just need to know,

What is difference between classification and regression score in Python scikit learn?

Is there any other way that i can calculate accuracy of my prediction algorithm?

```
r2_score(y_test,predictions)
f1_score(y_test,predictions)

Regression score (%)== 66%
Classification score (%) == 75%
```

Comment: assuming you have some training and testing data, build you model on the training data then run something like `algo = clf.fit()` and then `(Y_test == algo.predict(X_test)).mean()` . This will give you your accuracy. check out `sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error` and `sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error`

Comment: but i already evaluated my algorithm using
r2_score(y_test,predictions)
f1_score(y_test,predictions)
i just want to know the Difference between classification and regression score?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between classification and regression at all?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense to me, there are many ways to evaluate both regression and classification problems. Do you want to know the difference between r-squared and f1? If so, reading the documentation and/or wikipedia should answer that for you. Regardless, I don't see how this is a programming question suited for stackoverflow so I'm downvoting.

Comment: Classification trees have dependent variables that are categorical and unordered. Regression trees have dependent variables that are continuous values or ordered whole values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regression: the output variable takes continuous values.

Classification: the output variable takes class labels.

score will be calculated according to the result against continuous values and class labels